# Uploading image file with formData and Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

so i want to upload an image to a server which doesn't accept json payloads, but rather formData.
What i'm doing is

```js
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.set("access_token", globalState.access_token);
bodyFormData.set("listing_id", 2);
bodyFormData.append("image", Cookies.get("listingCover"));
```

but after this if i `console.log(bodyFormData)` it returns an empty object? Instead if i console.log(...bodyFormData) it returns 3 saperate arrays of each formdata that i set above. I want to be able to send it as `bodyFormData` in the body of the request like shown below. How do i do that?

```js
 axios({
    method,
    url: url,
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
```

Comment: `console.log(bodyFormData)` will not show anything, You can not console.log formData on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FormData.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) to console.log to see whats stored in your `formData`

You can not simply console.log(bodyFormData) it will NOT return anything.

Run snippet below.

```js
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.set("access_token", 'globalState.access_token');
bodyFormData.set("listing_id", 2);
bodyFormData.append("image", 'Cookies.get("listingCover")');

//Loop througt formData 
for (var data of bodyFormData.entries()) {
    console.log(data[0]+ ', ' + data[1]); 
}
```

You do no have any method when you are doing `axios` You need to set your method to `post` like below to send your `bodyFormData`

**Edit:** Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mxkLejrf/

=> In the demo you can see dev tools -> network the `bodyFormData` is being sent via POST

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'someEndPointUrl',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    // error
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: the `method` that i mentioned is actually "POST". i'm receiving it from a parameter. the snippet you posted above works fine, but when i send `bodyFormData` in the `data` property of axios. The formdata actually being sent is an empty object. I'm getting a no file provided error. Even though when logged in console i can see the blob file

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta  https://jsfiddle.net/mxkLejrf/

=> In the demo you can see dev tools -> network the bodyFormData is being sent via POST

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta Make sure You are ACTUALLY passing an image here `bodyFormData.append("image", Cookies.get("listingCover"))` AND this has an image `Cookies.get("listingCover")`

Comment: yeah, it is returning a blob file that i need when i log it so that shouldn't be an issue. I think its just something wrong with the backend API. Thanks for clarifying tho :)

Comment: im still frustrated that `formData.entires()` doesnt show up simply in `console.log`. So many frustrating hour's wasted.

Comment: I'm getting `Property 'set' does not exist on type 'FormData'.` error